# Binding class in Vue2 with method

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm new to Vue2 and have some trouble with binding a class based on an output of a function:

```
<ul v-for="sheep in sheeps">
    // sheep.listing = ['b', 'e', 'f'];
    // partners = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']
    <li v-for="foobar in partners" :class="{ done: hasPartnered(sheep.listing, foobar.name) }">
        <span v-text="foobar.name"></span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

In the example: sheep listed 3 letters from the 9 partners, so 3 times a true and the rest a false return..

With this Method:

```
hasPartnered(listing, partner) {
    if(listing) {
        listing.forEach(function(el) {
            if(el == partner) {
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
    return false;
},
```

It always returns `true;`. So probably it's not the correct way of binding a class in Vue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't return a value from `hasPartnered` from inside the function you pass to `forEach`.

Try this:

```js
hasPartnered(listing, partner) {
  return listing && listing.indexOf(partner) !== -1;
}
```